# Visual Studio "Start without debugging" Issue since v.15.7.1 upgrade

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

Today I upgraded visual studio professional 2017 to version 15.7.1 and since then I am not able to run multiple projects at the same time using the option "Start without debugging" (CTRL+F5).

The expected behavior would be to have an open cli window running my api and if I wished to start another project it would open another window and have both running parallel... This doesn't occur because if I start a second instance the first one is automatically closed.

Does anyone have this issue and know a solution?

**[UPDATED 18-06-2018]**

Just updated Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.7.3 and this issue seams to be solved.

Comment: I could debug three projects in my side using the VS2017 15.7.1 using "Multiple startup projects", I set the action for three project as "Start". Of course, I just debug three simple C# Console projects, could you check that whether all projects have the same issue? Please also reset your VS settings, and then re-set the solution properties, debug it again. If all projects still have this issue, I suggest you repair your VS firstly. But if just the specific projects have this issue, we would think about the project itself, or you could share a simple sample with one drive.

Comment: Would you please share the latest information about this issue in your side?

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work again. But due to some requirements of our project we ended up splitting our projects into multiple solutions which then "solved" the issue. When we still had multiple projects in one solution I would open a new CLI (which would  not automatically close if I start a project in VS) to run my second project I know this comment isn't much of a help but I would wait for a VS update to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue in VS 15.9.5. I could swear it worked in one of the earlier VS 15.9.x releases. Can sombody confim that this regression exits?

Answer (score 0):

Check the keyboard mapping.  Tools > Customize > Keyboard...

I had a similar problem on a recent update where F5 got remapped from Debug.Start to Debug.StartDebugTarget, which functions subtly differently.  It took me an afternoon to figure out what had happened.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately the F5 key is correctly mapped to Debug.Start and tried changing it as suggested but it didn't work.